# Save text from MS Word document from clipboard to variable and back with Interop

Tags: c#, ms-word, interop, clipboard

I have this code that take all MS Word document, save it to clipboard, save clipboard to variable a finally put it back to clipboard. It all run in BackgroundWorker, but that should not be problem.

```
wordDoc.StoryRanges[WdStoryType.wdMainTextStory].Copy();
IDataObject originalWordDocument = null;
System.Windows.Application.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(() => originalWordDocument = Clipboard.GetDataObject()));
...
System.Windows.Application.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(() => Clipboard.SetDataObject(originalWordDocument)));
```

The last line - specifically Clipboard.SetDataObject(originalWordDocument) throws this error:

> Invalid FORMATETC structure (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80040064 (DV_E_FORMATETC))

And this

```
originalWordDocument.GetFormats();
```

return array that contains

```
[0] "Object Descriptor" string
[1] "Rich Text Format"  string
[2] "HTML Format"   string
[3] "Text"  string
[4] "UnicodeText"   string
[5] "System.String" string
[6] "EnhancedMetafile"  string
[7] "System.Drawing.Imaging.Metafile"   string
[8] "MetaFilePict"  string
[9] "Embed Source"  string
```

Comment: Do you really need data in clipboard or there is a way to avoid that. Ask yourself as clipboard is not right method to transfer data. I don't have any Idea about c# or interop but as far as word is concern you can assign `data = wordDoc.Range.FormattedText` or `data = wordDoc.Range.Text`

Comment: @Rahul Well I have some Word template with placeholders and some data (items). Word contains template for report for one item but the final report could have multiple items. So I copy the original document, then fill template, paste new page with data from clipboard (new empty template) and fill it... So yes, I need clipboard.

But teoretically I don't need to save it to variable. But there is this problem http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37271243/replace-text-by-html-in-ms-word-by-interop

I need to solve just one of them to solve my global problem.

Comment: Save the items that are needed a variable number of times as BuidlingBlocks in the template. They can then be inserted as required.

Comment: I can't make changes in the template. I need to solve that on C# application side.